# Grub menu enters shell with Fedora 34 install

Tags: linux, multi-boot, fedora, grub, grub2

I recently did a Fedora 34 minimal install on my own PC. It works fine.
Same household, different PC: Grub greets me with a `grub>` shell. Typing `exit` worked as expected, I entered the normal menu and could start my Linux distro. I have read a lot of **"grub menu broken"** post, with is not an issue, it works, but it greets me with a shell.
It is a dual boot setup and Windows is accessible.
I unplugged the drive with Fedora on it and the grub shell is still there, when i type `exit` now, the screen goes black for a second and Windows is loaded, without asking me what i want to boot.
Is grub not being installed on my Linux partition and is that what triggers the console to open first? I reinstalled Fedora aswell, (before unplugging the drive) and nothing changed.